# Html markup for dropdown menu css BEM concept

Tags: html, css

I have recently started with the css BEM-Concept. I tried coding a drop-down menu,

```
<div class="menu menu-horizontal">
    <ul class="menu-list">
        <li class="menu-list__item menu-list__item-selected"> <a href="#" class="menu-list__link">1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-list__item"><a href="#" class="menu-list__link">2</a></li>
        <li class="menu-list__item"><a href="#" class="menu-list__link">3</a></li>
        <li class="menu-list__item menu-has-children menu-allow-hover"> <a href="#" class="menu-list__link">4</a>
            <ul class="menu-list-dropdown">
                <li class="menu-list-dropdown__item"><a href="#" class="menu-list-dropdown__link">4:1</a></li>
                <li class="menu-list-dropdown__item"><a href="#" class="menu-list-dropdown__link">4:2</a></li>
                <li class="menu-list-dropdown__item"><a href="#" class="menu-list-dropdown__link">4:3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Can you tell me if **this is correct**?, particularly after the `menu-list-dropdown` class (the second UL) and what if I need to have another drop-down for the drop-down, something like

```
<ul>
    <li>1
        <ul>
            <li>1:1</li>
            <li>1:2
                <ul>
                    <li>1:1:1</li>
                    <li>1:1:2</li>
                    <li>1:1:3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code `menu` is the Block  `ul` is an element so you should give it a class like

```
 .menu__list
```

The list items should be something like

```
.menu__list-item
```

So that `list-item` is targeting the list item and as a side note ,that doesn't qualify it to be nested like `&-item` if you are using a CSS preprocessor like sass since it's a bad practice (BEM is trying to reduce nesting and specificity)

The drop-down is more like component to me since you are most likely going to reuse it several places on your menus so I would have called it

```
.menu__dropdown
```

Then consider given it a state of open or close so that you will have a selector like

```
.menu__dropdown--isOpen
```

Since `--isOpen` is a modifier.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying, I found this https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/ ...there is a menu example there under the BEM Tree section and it is exactly the same as I did it. Can you please check.

Comment: Welcome, right now I am looking at https://mazipan.github.io/bem-kit/, its a BEM KIT and has a few example .. though I cannot confirm if it is completely based on the BEM concept but surely looks interesting.